# Using REST, How can you add a user to the User Information List so that he/she has a user ID?

Tags: 2013, rest, user-accounts, user-information-list

I want to create a form which allows users to search for a particular user who may not exist on the current site. I can do that using the SearchPrincipals web service, but the users will have an ID of -1 so I can't use that ID in order to set a people picker field in the background. Is there any way that we can add a user to the current site by his/her account name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the EnsureUser method of Web object by referring [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebEnsureUser). Here is the sample code which will check if the user exists (and return the SPUser object), if it doesn't, it will add the user and then return the SPUser object in JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/ensureuser ",
    type: "POST",
    data: "{ 'logonName': 'i:0#.f|membership|user@domain.onmicrosoft.com' }",
    headers: {
        "X-RequestDigest": < form digest value > ,
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Comment: It seems to be giving different results when I added the content-type underneath the accept header. Fingers crossed..

Comment: I'm having success when using this to search by a specific display name, email address, or account name. I wish there was a way to return a list of users like you have when you use SearchPrincipals. I could link the two together to provide a list since my organization has many users with the same display name, but they should all be able to search by email so that's more than acceptable. Can you add the content-type information to your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Added content-type header as it is required for the server to identify the type of data being sent along with the POST request. Please accept the answer if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Very much appreciated