# How to add users to a list by REST API before they are added to a list manually

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, person-or-group

I'm using SharePoint Online and SharePoint REST API v1.

I realize that after a user is added to people column of a list manually, I can get user ID and add this user to a column by the API.

But I need to add users in my organization who are not added to my list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [EnsureUser method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn499819(v=office.15)#ensureuser-method).

> Checks whether the specified login name belongs to a valid user in the site. If the user doesn't exist, adds the user to the site.

**Request example**:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web
    /ensureuser",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ 'logonName': 'i:0#.f|membership|user@domain.onmicrosoft.com' }",
  headers: {
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

This method will return user id in `success` function.

**Additional References**:

1. [Sharepoint 2013: EnsureUser via REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259576/sharepoint-2013-ensureuser-via-rest-api)
2. [Using REST, How can you add a user to the User Information List so that he/she has a user ID?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172116/using-rest-how-can-you-add-a-user-to-the-user-information-list-so-that-he-she-h)

Comment: I was looking for this feature! Thank you!